# Grouping my data according to one variable while I have some Nan values is not resulting in desired result

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

| ANO | WK | GRP | lgSc | TS | THS | GS | GHS | US |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 419 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 4 | 5 |
| 199 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 4 |
| 263 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 5 | 0 | 4 |

I am trying to group by the ANO but the result is either operation not callable or there is no change in the database
`grouped1=df1.groupby('ANO')`
I used this code but no desired result came though I did not receive any error.

This is a weekly study so same number repeats now I want to group a single patient number data to come together like this.

| ANO | WK | GRP | lgSc | TS | THS | GS | GHS | US |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 419 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 4 | 5 |
| 419 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 |
| 419 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 4 |

After applying the code I got no transformation.

There is one specialty in the data for some of the variables I have NaN data as no reading were taken for week 3 5 7 and 9 for 4 out of 12 variables

Comment: Do you want to do anything with grouped values? Like counting, calculating mean etc? Or else you might be looking for `sorted_df = df1.sort_values(by='ANO')`.

Comment: I tried sorted but couldn't apply over a multiple columns
I tried ```df1.sort_values(['ANO''WK','GRP'],ascending=[True,True,True])```
The only problem is I have priority like first group 1 should be together than for group 1 same patient should have same week sequence like ano 419 should be all together for week 1-9 and all the group 1 patients should be together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of pandas' `groupby` method is to split the data into groups and then apply some transformation or aggregation to those groups. See the pandas [user guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html).

If I understand you correctly, you simply want to sort the data, but not apply any transformations. You can do that like this:

```py
sorted1 = df1.sort_values(by='ANO')
```

The NaN values should not be an issue here.

Comment: I tried sorted but couldn't apply over a multiple columns
I tried ```df1.sort_values(['ANO''WK','GRP'],ascending=[True,True,True])```
The only problem is I have priority like first group 1 should be together than for group 1 same patient should have same week sequence like ano 419 should be all together for week 1-9 and all the group 1 patients should be together

Comment: That should work (except for the missing comma between 'ANO' and 'WK'). Don't forget to assign the result to a new dataframe name, or pass `inplace=True` as an argument to the sorting method.

Comment: ```df1.sort_values(['GRP','ANO','WK'],ascending=[True,True,True])``` Tried this and worked didnt knew sort also does in priority over the order in which it is kept
Thanks a lot